# Loop on Select_Analysis tool (Python and ArcGIS 9.3)

Tags: python, loops, arcgis, arcpy

First, I'm new in Python and I work on Arc GIS 9.3.

I'd like to realize a loop on the "Select_Analysis" tool. Indeed I have a layer "stations" composed of all the bus stations of a city.
The layer has a field "rte_id" that explains on what line a station is located.

And I'd like to save in distinct layers all the stations with "rte_id" = 1, the stations with "rte_id" = 2 and so on. Hence the use of the tool select_analysis.

So, I decided to make a loop (I have 70 different "rte_id" .... so 70 different layers to create!). But it does not work and I'm totally lost!

Here is my code:

```
import arcgisscripting, os, sys, string
gp = arcgisscripting.create(9.3)
gp.AddToolbox("C:/Program Files (x86)/ArcGIS/ArcToolbox/Toolboxes/Data Management Tools.tbx")
stations = "d:/Travaux/NantesMetropole/Traitements/SIG/stations.shp" 
field = "rte_id"

for i in field:
    gp.Select_Analysis (stations, "d:/Travaux/NantesMetropole/Traitements/SIG/stations_" + i + ".shp", field + "=" + i)
    i = i+1
    print "ok"
```

And here is the error message:

```
gp.Select_Analysis (stations, "d:/Travaux/NantesMetropole/Traitements/SIG/stations_" + i + ".shp", field + "=" + i)
TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list
```

Have you got any ideas to solve my problem?

Thanks in advance!
Julien

Answer (score 1):

The main problem here is in the string
`for i in field:`
You are trying to iterate a string - field name ("rte_id").

This is not correct.
You need to iterate all possible values of field "rte_id".

**Easiest solution:**
if you know that field "rte_id" have values 1 - 70 (for example) then you can try

```
    for i in range(1, 71):
        shp_name = "d:/Travaux/NantesMetropole/Traitements/SIG/stations_" + str(i) + ".shp"
        expression = '{0} = {1}'.format(field, i)
        gp.Select_Analysis (stations, shp_name , expression)
        print "ok"
```

**More sophisticated solution:**
You need to get a list of all unique values of field "rte_id" in terms of SQL - to perform GROUP BY.

I think it is not actually possible to perform GROUP BY operation on SHP files with one tool.

You can use SearchCursor, iterate through all features and generate a list of unique values of you field. But this is more complex task.

Another way is to use the Summarize option on the shapefile table in ArcMap (open table, right click on the column header). You will get dbf table with unique values which you can read in your script.

I hope it will help you to start!

Don't have ArcGIS right now and can't write and check any script.

Comment: Thank you very much Alex. I tried the first solution (the easiest!) but it didn't work. I have that error message :    expression = '{0} = {1}'.format(field, i)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'format'.         What could I do to correct that ?

Comment: Sorry, format method is only availiable in python 2.6+. Probably you are using 2.5. You can try this way: expression = field + ' = ' + str(i)

Comment: BTW I think you have to enclose field name in expression with double quotes (for SHP file!). So, result: `expression = '"rte_id" = ' + str(i)`

Comment: Ok thank you but another error has come. I used the expression with double quotes (indeed I work on python 2.5). And I have that message, meaning an error on Select_analysis function.     `gp.Select_Analysis (stations, shp_name , expression). 
ExecuteError: ERROR 999999: Error executing function.
An invalid SQL statement was used.
An invalid SQL statement was used.
Failed to execute (Select).` Do you have another idea ? Thanks !

Comment: May be there is a error in the field name or field type. i.e. if field rte_id is not of long type then you have also to modify your expression. It is better to test your expression in ArcCatalog by calling Select_Analysis tool from ArcToolbox and manually entering all params and expressions (for one value of rte_id). Try it until you get successful result and then just use that expression substituting constant value with you variable in the loop.

Comment: BTW it is a good way to start learning python for ArcGIS - first create a model in Model Builder. Try it for some constant values. Then export result to python script (there is such option in Model Builder) and modify it: put it into the loop, add some complex condition and logic etc.

Comment: Finally, the code worked ! I rebuildt my shapefile and checked the type of my fields. So the error should have been there. Thanks again for your help !

Answer (score 1):

You will need to make substantial changes to this code in order to get it to do what you want.  You may just want to download the [Split Layer By Attribute](http://arcscripts.esri.com/details.asp?dbid=14127) Code from ArcGIS online which does the exact same thing.